# Hibernate session issue

Tags: java, hibernate, session, servlets

> When you first attempt to use a session Hibernate will create one and
>   attach it to your local thread. When you commit the transaction in the
>   session Hibernate will automatically close the session meaning it
>   can’t be reused. - got this quote from this [site](http://www.17od.com/2006/11/06/using-managed-sessions-in-hibernate-to-ease-unit-testing/)

how ever this is what my code looks like ,and i can i do close my `hibernateSession` every time i commited transaction:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
   session.beginTransaction();
   session.getTransaction().commit();
   session.close();
```

**All of my code works fine,** but there is issue :
For example if i add row in to database,saving success,if i add another one after 1-10 seconds. Hibernate Exception occurs saying Session is closed. but this not happen if i add another one if i wait upto 1 minute. Is this somewhat wrong in my code or the server im connecting is slow(I do have this idea because updates on my java servlet code is sometimes delay)? Any idea?

Comment: can you pls post your hibernate.cfg.xml file ?

Comment: @monty024, my xml only have this setting for, driver,databasename,username,password, mySQL dialect, and mapping for a Fruit class.

Answer (score 1):

You did a good thing by opening a session whenever you need to commit a transaction but:

In general hibernate manages all the session closing and opening for you, so if you need to take the responsibility on your shoulders you need to change the following in hibernate config file : *hibernate.cfg.xml*

**Property Name:** `current_session_context_class`
**Property Value:** `managed`

To create a session and start a transaction you need this code:

```
org.hibernate.classic.Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
session.beginTransaction();
```

And to commit a transaction do the following:

```
ManagedSessionContext.unbind(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()); 
session.flush(); 
session.getTransaction().commit(); 
session.close();
```

Where you can be 100% sure that whenever you commit you un-attach the session from your thread and the gc will take care of it.

So whenever you need to do another transaction you need to run the first part of the code again.

Comment: is that why, if i remove the  `session.close();`, the HIbernate exception says, `transaction not successfully started`?

Comment: because hibernate seems to be committing the transaction before hand since it has the full control, you need to change the config... yes

Comment: and also is that solves the issue,that my code is working only on time element? like waiting for 1 minute?

Comment: i changed my code to what you have posted,but nothing happens, id still need to wait for a minute for the exception not to show

Comment: did you change the config and restarted the sever?

Comment: but are you doing this: org.hibernate.classic.Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
everytime?

Answer (score 0):

try using `.getCurrentSession()` instead of `openSession()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

use

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

To automatically close session when transaction is committed set below property as true in you hibernate configuration

```
hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session=true
```